# Creating a hashtable with values in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0, hashtable

Is it possible to create a hashtable "pre-populated" with values?

That is, something like:

```
dim myHash as new Hashtable() = {"key1", "value1", "key2", "value2" }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, Hashtable's are old now. Use a `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` instead. As for your question, with Visual Studio 2010 you can use the new [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx) syntax:

```
Dim myDict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String) From {{1, "One"}, {2, "Two"}}
```

Since you're on .NET 2.0, you can't use that syntax (you can and should still use a generic Dictionary), and so your best bet is using a method to hide it:

```
Function CreateDictionary() As Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    Dim d As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    d.Add(1, "One")
    d.Add(2, "Two")
    Return d
 End Function

Dim myDict As Dictionary(Of Integer, String) = CreateDictionary()
```

Comment: @chris - I updated your question to include that constraint.  If you need a particular version of the framework, please include that information in the future.   I'll update my answer as well, but it's gonna be similar to Jared's now.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to factor the code out into a function

```
Function CreateHashtable() As Hashtable
  Dim table = new HashTable()
  table.Add("key1", "value1")
  table.Add("key2", "value2")
  return table
End Function

Dim myHash As Hashtable = CreateHashtable()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    Dim myHash As New Hashtable() From {
        {"key1", "value1"}, {"key2", "value2"}
    }
```